# CLOSED - Python Selenium Can't find elements

Tags: python, windows, selenium, xpath

I have a problem with selenium with python 3.5, after install all the windows updates all my selenium script broken, I receive every time the same error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Carlo/Desktop/CEx/src/IE.py", line 12, in 
>       a=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='un']")
>     File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
>     File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']
>     File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to find element on closed window

But I really don't understand why because the window of IE is open!

This is my code (simple just to check why I can't make it work more):

```
import time from 
selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Ie()
driver.get('http://gala.test-platform.celtrino.com/Login.aspx')
time.sleep(10) 
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='un']")
```

The code fail every time in the last line and I double check with firepath and the xpath is correct so I don't really understand why it's not working.

Comment: `.//*[@id=')un']"` does it exact `XPath` you used or there's a typo in `id`? Obviously it is `"un"` but not `")un"`

Comment: I just selled wrong when I wrote here sorry :S I just correct it

Comment: I guess, it's not about your code, but about soft. Do you use up-to-date `IE webdriver-server` version?

Comment: Hi @Andersson Thanks so much to help me, I'm using this one: IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1

Comment: So it has to be `IE` browser issue. Its version probably was updated so you might need to downgrade to previous version

Comment: I try with the previous version as well :S Since my company installed the last windows update is not more working, I try different things but I'm not finding a solution for this reason I posted here :S

Comment: Can you try this solution: try going to Internet Options --> Security --> "Enable Protected Mode" on **all** zones should either be checked or **all** unchecked

Comment: @Andersson Thanks so so much, I try to enable everything before and wasn't working, now I unchecked all and it working :D tks so so much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew, IE has problems with xpath. It does not support xpath directly. It needs third party tools to do this. So, I suggest you to try cssSelector or any other options instead. Since, the element has an ID so you could use this. It's better.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("un");
```

Comment: Hi, I just solved the issue, wasn't regarding the xpath, the command now is correctly working, the issue was in the IE configuration:  Internet Options --> Security --> "Enable Protected Mode" on all zones should either be checked or all unchecked (I solved with all unchecked)